# How to add column header in an Excel file using xlsxwriter (without using Pandas)?

Tags: python, excel, list

I have a list `l1=[[12,23,45],[23,44,47],[34,67,88]]`. I want to save `l1` as an Excel file using `xlsxwriter` with the following format:

```
number1 number2 number3
12         23      45
23         44      47
34         67      88
```

Comment: Have you looked into [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want to use pandas then you can just use write function of xlsxwriter:

```
import xlsxwriter

l1=[[12,23,45],[23,44,47],[34,67,88]]

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('temp.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 0
for i in range(len(l1[0])):
    worksheet.write(row, i, "number"+str(i+1))
row += 1
for items in (l1):
    for i in range(len(items)):
        worksheet.write(row, i, items[i])
    row += 1
workbook.close()
```